# Enum type mutation for number, but not for string?

Tags: typescript

when I define an enum like this:

```js
enum Dir {
    Up: 1,
    Down: 2
}
```

And then initialize a variable with its type cast to the enum `Dir`:

```js
let dir: Dir;
dir = 3
```

I get no error. But when I make the enum string type like so,

```js
enum Dir {
    Up: 'Up',
    Down: 'Down'
}
```

And then,

```js
let dir: Dir;
dir = 'Left';
```

I get a compilation error. But in both cases, I assigned a value to `dir` variable that was not present in the enum. Why different behaviors for number and string types?

Comment: Numeric enums are intentionally mutually assignable to/from `number`, mostly to support bit fields (e.g., `let dir = Dir.Up | Dir.Down`).  See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26362.  I'm happy to write this up as an answer (although there are probably existing questions) but could you edit your code to form a [mre] without typos? [Your code is not valid TypeScript](https://tsplay.dev/mbdX3w).

Comment: Please see the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57334349/typescript-why-is-exact-enum-type-not-enforced or  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53496711/number-enum-in-typescript-allows-any-number-whereas-string-enum-does-not for more information.