# Why any number value can be used in interface member declared with enum literal type?

Tags: typescript

I have the following typescript enum:

```
enum Status {
    READY = 0,
    FAILED = 1
}
```

and the following interface:

```
interface ReadyItem {
    id: number;
    status: Status.READY;
}
```

Why am I able to redeclare the value of status in the following case?

```
const readyItem: ReadyItem = {
    id: 1,
    status: 58 // no error here
}
```

If I change my enum number values to string values, it works as intended:

```
enum Status {
    READY = "ready",
    FAILED = "failed"
}

interface ReadyItem {
    id: number;
    status: Status.READY;
}

const readyItem = {
    id: 1,
    status: 'other' // error: Type 'other' is not assignable to type 'Status.READY'.
}
```

Can someone tell me how I can have this behavior with number values?

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAygLgQzmAzlA3gKCjqAlAUQEEARATSgF4oAmAGm1wDEiBJAGQJKqgEZMAvpkwBLEHGAAnAGYIAxsHzAEAEwCerCdCy4oIlQC4o4CACMpAbkY4UiZCiPwkqAHSFSZK0MxyA9iFsoSWV1TWAIIzwQjS0eHVx9I14GXVtnBygAVgAOKAB6PONfKClJX0koAAspYEEgA)

Comment: What is the value of `Permission.READY`? Did you mean `Status.READY`?

Comment: Yep that's what I meant. It's because I simplified the example from my code. I also changed the question a little bit

Comment: Interesting question. Confirms my suspicions that `enum` is to be avoided because it's just plain weird and doesn't map to anything javascripty. [Number enum in TypeScript allows any number whereas string enum does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53496711/number-enum-in-typescript-allows-any-number-whereas-string-enum-does-not)

Comment: https://twitter.com/mpocock1/status/1513459135358160900

Comment: I think that `enum` can be very useful when you have a node backend which inserts the value in database. I prefer to use number values instead of string values in db. But this kind of behavior is quite annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
...
interface ReadyItem {
    id: number;
    status: Status;
}
...
```

Now you're constraining `status` prop to accept only one value from enum

Comment: What if I want to force status of ReadyItem to Status.READY? How can I achieve that?

Comment: @Moussamoa What do you mean by forcing? Setting the initial value?